# How to fix get Key By Value with duplicate values in Java

Tags: java

I want to getKey by with duplicate values in map, but the result is not correct, an I have this code for example

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("A", 10);
        map.put("B", 20);
        map.put("C", 30);
        map.put("D", 10);
        map.put("E", 11);
        map.put("F", 30);

        System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
        }

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(list);
        Collections.reverse(list);

        System.out.println("\nAfter Sorting:");
        for (Integer entry : list) {
            System.out.println(getKeyByValue(map, entry) + " - " + entry);
        }
    }

    public static <String, Integer> String getKeyByValue(
        Map<String, Integer> map, Integer value) {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

for now the result of the output is

```
Before Sorting:
A - 10
B - 20
C - 30
D - 10
E - 11
F - 30

After Sorting:
C - 30
C - 30
B - 20
E - 11
A - 10
A - 10
```

and the goal is to sort the values in descending order and then get the keys from the values, but since there are duplicate values, I could not get the keys

```
After Sorting should be:
F - 30
C - 30
B - 20
E - 11
D - 10
A - 10
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You are looking for the key which has a value of `30` - the `map` is not sorted, so why do you think that it should not return `C` ?

Comment: because the F key also has value 30, it should be return the two keys (F and C)

Comment: But as soon as you find one `key` you do `return entry.getKey();`